# What AS3 can do (and previous AS versions can't)

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm looking for a list of things ActionScript 3 can do and previous versions can't. Could you post some links?

Comment: duplicated?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116598/flash-actionscript-3-capabilities-lacking-in-actionscript-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peter Elst's:

[Slide detailing timeline history of ActionScript and new features in ActionScript3](http://www.slideshare.net/peterelst/skillsmatter-inthebrain-session-whats-new-in-actionscript-30)

[Video podcast detailing new features of ActionScript3](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/ajax-ria/whats-new-in-actionscript-30)